# @interface default declaration usage in Java

Tags: java, annotations

I have just discovered this feature.

Declaring an interface using the "@interface" syntax allows you to put a default value.

```
public @interface HelloWorld { 
     public String sayHello() default "hello world";
}
```

This is something new for me. How is that default value suppose to be used.

I cannot find references to that, because the www is full of java interface documents prior to "@" addition in Java 1.5 ( was it on .5 or in .4? )

---

**EDIT**

Thanks for the answers <sub>( I was somehow close to "annotation", for I use the tag already )  :P</sub>

I knew I should've read that document years ago!!!... let's see...

> *Many APIs require a fair amount of boilerplate code. For....*

Comment: And not to be confused with Java 8 default interface methods: http://java.dzone.com/articles/interface-default-methods-java

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You have just written an [annotation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html).

Regarding the `default` statement in particular: This is used because annotations and interfaces can't have constructors, so this is the only way to have a default value for an annotation attribute. From the [Java Language Specification](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#253974):

> An annotation type element may have a default value specified for it. This is done by following its (empty) parameter list with the keyword `default` and the default value of the element.
>
> Defaults are applied dynamically at the time annotations are read; default values are not compiled into annotations. Thus, changing a default value affects annotations even in classes that were compiled before the change was made (presuming these annotations lack an explicit value for the defaulted element).

I note that none of the annotations in [java.lang.annotation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/package-summary.html) use default values, though.

---

**Usage:** You have an annotation `@HelloWorld` with an attribute `sayHello`. You could put it on a class like this:

```
@HelloWorld(sayHello="Hi")
public class MyClass {
}
```

Since you have a default value, you could just put

```
@HelloWorld
public class MyClass {
}
```

(Note that the document says, "In annotations with a single element, the element should be named `value`"; I believe the only reason to do this is that you could just write `@HelloWorld("Hi")` without having to name the parameter.)

As written, your annotation can be used on any valid program element (including methods and variable declarations). You can change this with the [`@Target`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Target.html) annotation.

Finally, setting the [`RetentionPolicy`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/RetentionPolicy.html) lets you decide if the annotation should be discarded by the compiler, discarded by the VM, or kept always.

---

Two packages that might also be interesting: [javax.annotation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/package-summary.html) and [javax.annotation.processing](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/package-summary.html). And [here](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/04/10/source-code-analysis-using-java-6-compiler-apis.html) is an example of using annotation processing for source code analysis.

Comment: +1: Thank you mmyers: Do you have any  summary for this lazy programmer?

Comment: Summary of what? All uses of annotations?

Comment: No, only of the @interface usage... I'll look at the link... later  :-/

Comment: OK, executive summary: Annotations are very useful for source code analysis and for code generation (many web frameworks do this). Good enough?

Comment: @mmyers: And test frameworks too of course. Ok, then, what I've posted is how the annotation is declared. Then to use it I just annotate the class I need ( does it applies to methods and interfaces too ) What about attributes?  And then, using an annotation processing tool you read them. Am I right?

Comment: @mmyers: Thanks a lot for the last edit. It make a difference :)

Answer (score 4):

That's an [annotation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/annotations.html) you are declaring not an interface. It was added in Java 1.5.

Comment: +1. Oh.. yes, the annotation. I think I dismiss the lecture for those when I said "When I need to create an annotation processing tool I'll come to that"   Today I was looking at the Groovy Source code and that was the first thing that puzzle me.