# default {} in @interface in Spring

Tags: java, annotations, default-value

Just read some source code from Spring-web-4.2.4, found that the `ControllerAdvice` (annotation) is pretty interesting:

```
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Component
public @interface ControllerAdvice {
  @AliasFor("basePackages")
  String[] value() default {};

  @AliasFor("value")
  String[] basePackages() default {};

  //......
}
```

I do not consider `default {}` as the new feature of Java 8?

Comment: "default" is new feature of Java 8 but only for "interface", not for "@interface".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Interface with default methods vs Abstract class in Java 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19998454/interface-with-default-methods-vs-abstract-class-in-java-8)

Comment: Later found that it is just Java annotation behaviour, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588056/interface-default-declaration-usage-in-java explained before..Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java `@interface` is a some kind of reserved word (keyword) for defining [`annotations`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/declaring.html). So you can be sure that the class you listed above is an annotation definition. In this classes `default` keyword could be used to define default value for annotation properties. This feature was introduced at the same time as annotations were introduced in the language.

Comment: You are absolutely right..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588056/interface-default-declaration-usage-in-java
Explains a bit around it. Thanks dude.

Answer (score 2):

1. The `default` keyword is used in annotations to set *a default value* for a corresponding *annotation type* (it, in turn, allows you not to specify a value of this type every time you write the annotation);
2. `{}` is just an array literal which means *an empty array*.