# How to read a default value specified in @interface

Tags: java, annotations

I am trying to understand why I would use @interface. I see many tutorials explaining what all those annotations mean but no where could I find in simple terms how (or why) I can use them.

As a made up example

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface MyAnnotation {
    String getAString() default "blah";
}
```

Suppose I use this annotation on a class.

```
@MyAnnotation
public class TestClass {

    public String test(){
        return this.getAString();
    }
}
```

- Can I call getAString() without using reflection?
- If not, what can be
  a possible use of it?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example on how you can use annotation fields:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)

public @interface MyAnnotation {
    public String name();
    public String value();
}


for(Annotation annotation : annotations){
    if(annotation instanceof MyAnnotation){
        MyAnnotation myAnnotation = (MyAnnotation) annotation;
        System.out.println("name: " + myAnnotation.name());
        System.out.println("value: " + myAnnotation.value());
    }
}
```

The example is taken from here:
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/annotations.html

Also see this:
[@interface default declaration usage in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588056/interface-default-declaration-usage-in-java)